# class instantiation without calling super in all constructors

Tags: ios, inheritance, constructor, initialization

I have the following situation:
I'm extending `UITextView control (MyTextView : UITextView)`. I have different implementations according to the runtime device version. So currently I have many “if-else” statements in my implementation of `MyTextView` class.

In order to make it more maintainable, I would like to split it into different classes:

`MyTextViewIos5 : MyTextView`, `MyTextViewIos6:MyTextView`

and *to create a factory function which will know in runtime which subclass to create according to the device iOS version*.

This solution works perfectly if I'm using MyTextView as a parameter.

```
MyTextView* textView = [Factory createWithFrame:frame];
```

The problem begins when there is a class which inherits from `MyTextView (externalTextView:MyTextView)` and extends it with specific methods,
its `initWithFrame` method will look like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [Factory createWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Instead of calling super `initwithFrame` I'm calling my factory.

When I call `externalTextView` specific method, the app crashes with an error that *MyTextViewIos5* or *MyTextViewIos6* does not implement the specific method that was called.

Is there a workaround for making it work?

Comment: why don't you want to call `super` in the init method?

Comment: I was thinking for a moment that you could handle this by subclassing `alloc`, but probably not.  (It is a "clever" way to handle your original problem, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply assigning `self = [Factory createWithFrame:]` only inits data for `MyTextViewIos5` or `MyTextViewIos6` and not your custom class. As a result, the method tables etc for your custom class don't exist and that is why it crashes.

The nature of inheritance is that you must either subclass `MyTextViewIos5` `MyTextViewIos6` in order to inherit their features. The problem is you won't know which.

I would recommend separating the functionality of the custom class into a delegate/protocol design. The MyTextView superclass could contain the code for managing the delegate.

Something like:

```
- (void)methodCustomSubclassWouldHaveOverridden
{ 
   [delegate handleThisForMe];
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution if i know what is going to be the custom class functionality.
but in my case, I'm building an external SDK and i cannot assume anything about the custom class which is going to use\inherit MyTextView class.

Comment: @user2572953 by using a protocol you can define the contract the client needs to implement.

Comment: sorry, my fault… i didn't understand your solution correctly at the first time.
you are right, putting my custom functionality in a delegate and handle it in MyTextView class will work. this means that my custom ios5&ios6 classes won't be subclasses of MyTextView and will just implement the protocol that will be defined by it.
this approach will work, but is much less elegant than using inheritance. if I won't have any other alternatives I will use it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Each one of the classes you derive from `MyTextView` shall call `[super initWithFrame]` in its  own `initWithFrame` method, if you define one. If you do not need doing any custom initialization of your derived classes instances, you could simply leave out the init method altogether.

In the general case, your factory `createWithFrame` should be something like:

```
- (MyTextView*)createWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if (<iOS6>)
         return [[MyTextViewOS6 alloc] initWithFrame];
    if (<iOS5>)
         ...
}
```

Now, if your derived classes do not need any special initialization, you could simply spare the `initWIthFrame` method in each of them (and define one only in the base class).

Alternatively, you could do the initialization in the factory, like this:

```
- (MyTextView*)createWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if (<iOS6>)
         MyTextViewOS6* view = [[MyTextViewOS6 alloc] initWithFrame];
         view.iOS6SpecificProperty = ...;
         [view iOS6SpecificMethod:...];
         return view;
    if (<iOS5>)
         ...
}
```

What you are doing with:

```
self = [Factory createWithFrame:frame];
```

is allocating a new instance of `MyTextView` and replacing `self` original value. In other words, when you do:

```
externalTextView* view = [[externalTextView alloc] initWithFrame];
```

first of all memory is allocated for an object of type `externalTextView`; then, the initWithFrame method of that class is called. Now, if inside of initWithFrame you do:

```
self = [Factory createWithFrame:frame];
```

you are instantiating a new object through the factory and assigning a pointer to it to `self` (which originally pointed to the object created through alloc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately, like Justin mentioned "Simply assigning self = [Factory createWithFrame:] only inits data for MyTextViewIos5 orMyTextViewIos6 and not your custom class. As a result, the method tables etc for your custom class don't exist and that is why it crashes".